# File Versioning on C: in Windows 10

Tags: file-management, windows-10

In Windows 7 there was a file history feature, where Windows would save multiple versions of files. It could be done locally on C: drive itself. Meaning, you didn't need to have a separate partition or external drive.

But Windows 10 doesn't have that option.

Is there any program to have file versioning on C: in Windows 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**VBackup** : https://www.fileviewer.com/vbackup/

Free, command-line tool.
It is similar in functionality to XCOPY and ROBOCOPY, however, VBackup implements file versioning.
Have used it for a number of years.

Comment: Another potential option is SyncBack by 2BrightSparks. Their SyncBack SE product has versioning, but is not free.

Comment: Thanks. Does VBackup let you see the list of versions for a selected file and choose which to recover?

Comment: By default, VBackup creates "backup sets" which you can use to restore using the VBackup program. You can also restore files manually. Versioned files are stored in full (not as block-level deltas).

Comment: Thanks David. Even Windows File History stores updated files as full size copies. In that regard what do you think of Duplicati, as I believe it does block-level versioning?

Comment: I did look at Duplicati when transitioning off Crashplan when they closed their free home plan. I was looking for a program to keep an off-site backup up to date (just mirror, not versioning). At that point they were in process of creating a new version of Duplicati which wasn't complete. Also, their solution seemed very complex - and my preference is for simplicity. 

In the end for my off-site backup solution, I used DeltaCopy, which is a wrapper around the venerable rsync program. Can't comment on Duplicati for versioning, but it seemed like it was building into a solid offering.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll research these programs a bit more. Appreciate your feedback.